# How to show Query in Symfony 2.1

Tags: php, symfony

Situation:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->addSelect(  /* hardlyPredictableSelectString() */ )
    ->leftjoin (  /* hardlyPredictableJoinString()   */ )
    ->andWhere (  /* hardlyPredictableWhereString()  */ )
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
```

I want to debug that query, but it is hardly to predictable. You know, if, else, add some text, or not... I can not simply echo $string, , so my question is:
How to make something like that? `$queryString=getQueryString()` ?

getDQLParts(); is not good idea, because, I want to simply copy and paste that string to custom MySQL Manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use getSql before getResult.

```
$query = $queryBuilder
    ->addSelect(  /* hardlyPredictableSelectString() */ )
    ->leftjoin (  /* hardlyPredictableJoinString()   */ )
    ->andWhere (  /* hardlyPredictableWhereString()  */ )
    ->getQuery();

echo $query->getSql();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use symfony profiler, where You have Doctrine|Propel tab in which there is list of queries that was executed.